# How can I slove postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 unmet dependencies Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, postgresql

I've installed PostgreSQL v9.3 (database) on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm currently attempting to install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.9.0) but it is
>   not installable
>                                 Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
>                                 Depends: liblwgeom-2.1.7 (>= 2.1.6) but it is not going to be installed
>                                 Depends: libproj0 (>= 4.8.0-1) but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

Please Note: I have already successfully installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.3 
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1-scripts
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: if you try `sudo apt-get install -f` what happens?

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 produces the same error postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libgdal1  etc...

Comment: The versions required seem odd, e.g.liblwgeom-2.1.7 (>= 2.1.6), when the version of liblwgeom is 2.1.2 in the standard 14.04 repostiories.  Starting from a standard postresql 9.3, postgis may be installed, and it pulls in the 2.1.2 version of liblwgeom, but then trying to install  postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 results in a need to reinstallation of postgres-9.3!  What repositories are you using?

Comment: Under Ubuntu Software tab, enable all the repositories We are not all running ubuntu with a UI. So I can't follow your answer with ``software-properties-gtk``. Moreover, you may have added some repositories by yourself before. Can you give the list of repositories do you have enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research I found the answer via the following questions
[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa#answer-142808) which can be applied to this question as a solution.

In your terminal run

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Under Ubuntu Software tab, enable all the repositories

Next run

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Finally run

```
sudo apt-get install  postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

Worked successfully for me I hope this helps someone with the same issue install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 with unmet dependencies on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem while provisioning an Ubuntu 14.04 box with Vagrant using a configuration that used to work:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: liblwgeom-2.1.2 (>= 2.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

It turns out there was a conflict with the official Ubuntu repository and the Postgresql.org repository and ubuntugis ppa. Not adding those repositories as sources when provisioning the box fixed the issue for me.